In what way is a joint distribution determined by the expectations and covariances?


When they say "that the joint distribution of $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$", as in the text in the image which I highlighted (with a green ink), are they talking the joint cumulative distribution function (cdf) $F$ of the random variables $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$, i.e. $$F:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$$ such that $$F(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)=\Bbb P(X_1=x_1,...,X_n=x_n)?$$ But nowhere in the image I can see where they found the  cdf of the random variables. This seems really strange for they are saying, "which shows that the joint distribution of $X_1,\dotsc,X_m$ is completely determined from a knowledge of the values of $E[X_i]$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)$, $i,j=1,\dotsc,m$," but when did they find the cdf? Did I miss something?

CDF, PDF and characteristic function are all equivalent. In order words, if you know one, you can deduce these two others. And as the characteristic function here depends on only values of the means and covariances, so do the CDF and the joint distribution.

@NN2 Well, from the MGF how will you determine the joint cdf?

By Fourier inversion. See the last comment of this answer

And for MGF, here on page 3 ('Proof of Def 2 ⇒ Def 3')

Hi: Usually F is used for the cdf but, in this case, it seems like it denotes the joint density of $X_{i}$. Also, for the case of the normal disitribution, you don't actually need to do the Fourier inversion. If you look at how the inversion is done in the univariate case, then you can back out the joint case.

@NN2 I need a bit clarification. When you say, "CDF, PDF and characteristic function are all equivalent." I hope by characteristic function you mean the moment generating function (MGF), right? Also, dies this mean, " (i) if any two RVs X and Y have the same MGF then they also have the same PDF and CDF, (ii) if X and Y they have the same CDF then they have the same PDF and MGF, (iii) if X and Y have the same PDF then they have the same CDF and MGF" , right?

@ThomasFinley The MGF need not exist for all random variables since $E(e^{tX})$ need not be finite. However, the Characteristic Function which is $E(e^{itX})$ always exists (as $|e^{itx}|\leq 1$ . For Normal/Multivariate Normal however, the MGF exists for all $t\in\Bbb{R}$ and hence looking at the MGF suffices. And yes, if two random variables have the same MGF, then they have the same CDF and hence also the same pdf(if it exists, i.e. if the rv is absolutely continuous). It will be wise for you to actually ponder over the questions $(ii)$ and $(iii)$ yourself.

@ThomasFinley For example suppose the pdf is $f$. Then the cdf is $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(y),dy$. Isn't it obvious that $f$ completely determines $F$? . The Characteristic function (i.e. the Fourier transoform) completely determines the cdf (distribution of a random variable) and conversely, the cdf of a random variable completely determines the characteristic function. Here, they are using MGF. And if the MGF exists for all $t\in (-a,a)$ for some $a>0$, then the MGF completely determines the cdf and the cdf completely determines the MGF. Here the MGF exists for all $t\in\Bbb{R}$.

To put it in short. The Characteristic Function completely Characterizes the distribution and thus it is named that way .See the Fourier inversion formula here to know how it does so explicitly.
